# Load on PostgreSQL server

Tags: postgresql, performance, load, replication

I have setup replication between two servers. There are no long-time running queries and no errors in error log. But the load keep's on increasing. So, what are the other factors that might affect the server load and performance?

Comment: What do you mean by LOAD KEEPS INCREASING, what are your metrics and how are you identifying increasing load pattern

Comment: Normally the load of our server ranges around 2-5. But now it's around 16 and not even decreasing. Using w and top i can see the load increasing on server.

Comment: Not very helpful, 2-5 without a context/unit and how it is gauged is not very helpful. Not for me at-least.

Comment: Which server, the master or the replica?  Are you using physical or logical replication?

Comment: load average: 14.30, 15.17, 15.32  which got increased four times . Load on Master sever got increased and we are using logical replication that contains two slaves.